# Is there a command or subroutine for LU factorization?

Tags: fortran, lapack

In MatLab, the command lu(A) gives as output the two matrices L and U, that is, the LU factorization of A. I was wondering whether there is some command in Fortran doing exactly the same. I have not been able to find it anywhere. I found a lot of subroutines of LAPACK which solve linear systems by first performing the LU factorization, but for my purpouses I need to specifically perform the LU factorization and store the L and U matrices.

Is there a command or subroutine which has as input a square matrix A and as outputs the matrices L and U of the LU factorization?

Comment: What is your question? Why is not DGBTRF from LAPACK suitable?

Comment: My question: Is there a command or subroutine which has as input a square matrix A and as outputs the matrices L and U of the LU factorization?   I did not know about DGBTRF. I'll try to use that. It's a bit far-fetched for my specific purpouse though. Something as simple as MatLab's [L,U]=lu(A) would have been nicer, no?  I don't see how storing the matrices L and U in the same array is an advantage at all (That's what is done, according to the documentation I've just looked up)

Comment: It is an advantage, because you save a lot of memory. BTW, finding DGBTRF took me less than one minute  by googling "LAPACK LU".

Comment: @Qwertuy: Once you have the LU decomposition in a single matrix, you can further process the triangular parts separately by other LAPACK routines. These routines only use one of the triangular parts and don't access the rest of the "2-in-1-matrix" dgbtrf puts out.

Comment: You can write a wrapper routine for dgetrf() or dgbtrf() that mimics Matlab. Actually I'm trying to write such an example, but now having trouble with ipiv(:)... XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in command that corresponds to `lu` in Matlab, but we can write a simple wrapper to `dgetrf` in LAPACK such that the interface is similar to `lu`, e.g.,

```
module linalg
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.0d0)
contains
    subroutine lufact( A, L, U, P )
        !... P * A = L * U
        !... http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgetrf.f.html
        !... (note that the definition of P is opposite to that of the above page)

        real(dp), intent(in) :: A(:,:)
        real(dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: L, U, P
        integer, allocatable  :: ipiv(:)
        real(dp), allocatable :: row(:)
        integer :: i, n, info

        n = size( A, 1 )
        allocate( L( n, n ), U( n, n ), P( n, n ), ipiv( n ), row( n ) )

        L = A
        call DGETRF( n, n, L, n, ipiv, info )
        if ( info /= 0 ) stop "lufact: info /= 0"

        U = 0.0d0
        P = 0.0d0
        do i = 1, n
            U( i, i:n ) = L( i, i:n )
            L( i, i:n ) = 0.0d0
            L( i, i )   = 1.0d0
            P( i, i )   = 1.0d0
        enddo

        !... Assuming that P = P[ipiv(n),n] * ... * P[ipiv(1),1]
        !... where P[i,j] is a permutation matrix for i- and j-th rows.
        do i = 1, n
            row = P( i, : )
            P( i, : ) = P( ipiv(i), : )
            P( ipiv(i), : ) = row
        enddo
    endsubroutine
end module
```

Then, we can test the routine with a 3x3 matrix shown in the Matlab page for lu():

```
program test_lu
    use linalg
    implicit none
    real(dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A, L, U, P

    allocate( A( 3, 3 ) )

    A( 1, : ) = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    A( 2, : ) = [ 4, 5, 6 ]
    A( 3, : ) = [ 7, 8, 0 ]

    call lufact( A, L, U, P )  !<--> [L,U,P] = lu( A ) in Matlab

    call show( "A =", A )
    call show( "L =", L )
    call show( "U =", U )
    call show( "P =", P )

    call show( "P * A =", matmul( P, A ) )
    call show( "L * U =", matmul( L, U ) )

    call show( "P' * L * U =", matmul( transpose(P), matmul( L, U ) ) )

contains
    subroutine show( msg, X )
        character(*) :: msg
        real(dp) :: X(:,:)
        integer i
        print "(/,a)", trim( msg )
        do i = 1, size(X,1)
            print "(*(f8.4))", X( i, : )
        enddo
    endsubroutine
end program
```

which gives the expected result:

```
A =
  1.0000  2.0000  3.0000
  4.0000  5.0000  6.0000
  7.0000  8.0000  0.0000

L =
  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.1429  1.0000  0.0000
  0.5714  0.5000  1.0000

U =
  7.0000  8.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.8571  3.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  4.5000

P =
  0.0000  0.0000  1.0000
  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000

P * A =
  7.0000  8.0000  0.0000
  1.0000  2.0000  3.0000
  4.0000  5.0000  6.0000

L * U =
  7.0000  8.0000  0.0000
  1.0000  2.0000  3.0000
  4.0000  5.0000  6.0000

P' * L * U =
  1.0000  2.0000  3.0000
  4.0000  5.0000  6.0000
  7.0000  8.0000  0.0000
```

Here please note that the inverse of `P` is given by its transpose (i.e., `inv(P) = P' = transpose(P)`) because `P` is the product of (elementary) permutation matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I have added an method to compute LU using DOLITTLE method. Which is used by MATLAB to computed LU for faster computation involving larger matrices. The algorithm is as follows. To execute the algorithm you have to provide an input file in the format given below. Since the algorithm is a subroutine, you can add it to your code and call it whenever required. Algorithm, input file, output file are as follows.

```
  PROGRAM DOLITTLE
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: n
  !**********************************************************
  ! READS THE NUMBER OF EQUATIONS TO BE SOLVED.
  OPEN(UNIT=1,FILE='input.dat',ACTION='READ',STATUS='OLD')
  READ(1,*) n
  CLOSE(1)
  !**********************************************************

  CALL LU(n)
  END PROGRAM


    !==========================================================
    ! SUBROUTINES TO MAIN PROGRAM
    SUBROUTINE LU(n)
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: i,j,k,p,n,z,ii,itr = 500000
    REAL(KIND=8) :: temporary,s1,s2
    REAL(KIND=8),DIMENSION(1:n) :: x,b,y
    REAL(KIND=8),DIMENSION(1:n,1:n) :: A,U,L,TEMP
    REAL(KIND=8),DIMENSION(1:n,1:n+1) :: AB

    ! READING THE SYSTEM OF EQUATIONS

    OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE='input.dat',ACTION='READ',STATUS='OLD')
    READ(2,*)
    DO I=1,N
         READ(2,*) A(I,:)
    END DO
    DO I=1,N
         READ(2,*) B(I)
    END DO
    CLOSE(2)

    DO z=1,itr
         U(:,:) = 0
         L(:,:) = 0
         DO j = 1,n
              L(j,j) = 1.0d0
         END DO
         DO j = 1,n
              U(1,j) = A(1,j)
         END DO

         DO i=2,n
             DO j=1,n
                  DO k=1,i1
                       s1=0
                       if (k==1)then
                        s1=0
                       else
                        DO p=1,k1
                         s1=s1+L(i,p)*U(p,k)
                        end DO
                       endif
                       L(i,k)=(A(i,k)-s1)/U(k,k)
                  END DO
                  DO k=i,n
                       s2=0
                       DO p=1,i-1
                       s2=s2+l(i,p)*u(p,k)
                       END DO
                       U(i,k)=A(i,k)*s2
                  END DO
             END DO
        END DO
        IF(z.eq.1)THEN
        OPEN(UNIT=3,FILE='output.dat',ACTION='write')
        WRITE(3,*) ''
        WRITE(3,*) '********** SOLUTIONS *********************'
        WRITE(3,*) ''
        WRITE(3,*) ''
        WRITE(3,*) 'UPPER TRIANGULAR MATRIX'
        DO I=1,N
             WRITE(3,*) U(I,:)
        END DO
        WRITE(3,*) ''
        WRITE(3,*) ''
        WRITE(3,*) 'LOWER TRIANGULAR MATRIX'
        DO I=1,N
             WRITE(3,*) L(I,:)
        END DO
   END SUBROUTINE
```

Here goes the input file format for system Ax=B. First line is number of equations, next three lines are the A matrix element, next three lines are B vector ,

```
      3
      10 8 3
      3 20 1
      4 5 15
      18
      23
      9
```

And the output is generated as,

```
      ********** SOLUTIONS *********************
      UPPER TRIANGULAR MATRIX
      10.000000000000000 8.0000000000000000 3.0000000000000000
      0.0000000000000000 17.600000000000001 0.1000000000000009
      0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000 13.789772727272727
      LOWER TRIANGULAR MATRIX
      1.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000
      0.2999999999999999 1.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000
      0.4000000000000002 0.1022727272727273 1.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Everytime someone writes `real(kind=8)` God kills a kitten.

Comment: Also don't use units 1,2,3. Low numbers tend to be used for special purposes. Most often 0,5 and 6 but that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "numerical recipes in fortran 77",
there was LU decomposition subroutine.

There are a lot of useful subroutines, linalg, stasistics, etc.